# Is this code leaking memory? Do I need to free anything? C++ memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, free

so I was writing some matrix classes in C++. So each matrix has a pointer to an array called entries, I am not sure if i'm doing this right but I am redeclaring the array in the sub class. (I'm no expert in C++)

Does this memory need to be free'd? Am I simply overwriting the pointer with the referenced array? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
class Matrix {
protected:
    float* entries;
public:
    int rows;
    int cols;


    Matrix() {
    }
    ~Matrix() {
    }
};

class Matrix4x4 : public Matrix {
    protected:
        float entry[4][4];
    public:

    /* This will create an empty matrix */
    Matrix4x4() {
        //Define the size of the arrays
        rows = 4;
        cols = 4;
        this->empty();
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Why do you define rows and cols as float? (C++ could not handle fractal dimensioned matrices (;-)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice that I franticly typed this out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code isn't leaking memory and cannot possibly do so, since you never say `new` or `malloc` anywhere in your code*, nor do you call functions which do so in an unguarded fashion (i.e. outside RAII objects).

However, the code is also fairly useless and misguided (e.g. `Matrix4x4::entry` is *hiding* the vestigial `Matrix::entry`, and `rows` and `columns` seem to be somewhat redundant variables), and that can only be solved by sitting down with a good C++ book for a few hours.

<sub>*) or, as @Nicol Bolas has helpfully pointed out, `make_shared` together with a lost circular reference</sub>

Comment: And that's the reason why I don't like `strdup`, it makes your first sentence false. But +1 :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: There's no "`strdup`" in C or C++, but of course I should have said that "you never *say or call any functions that* say `new` or `malloc`." Caveat Usor.

Comment: @DannyBirch: I know what you're trying to do. I just noted that you're most likely not doing it right :-)

Comment: "The code isn't leaking memory and cannot possibly do so, since you never say new or malloc anywhere." You can leak memory with `shared_ptr`. All you need is a circular reference.

Comment: I am using the row and col to compare when doing addition or multiplication or something, there is probably another way I dunno. Should I delete the pointer to the entires in the base class then? I was trying to overload using the Matrix class so I can loop and add the rows/cols of any size Matrix but I think i'm just making a mess

Comment: @NicolBolas: Fine, add `make_shared` to the list :-)

Comment: Did you mean "RAII" instead of "RIAA" or is that some new acronym I don't know? Or does the recording industry make some new objects for managing memory in C++?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I do. I was somehow thinking about copying and the prohibition thereof and the rule of three when I typed that. Thanks!